# Oracle Concurrency Problem with competing race condition

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, concurrency, race-condition, multiple-instances

I am facing a concurrency problem with Oracle DB. Say I have 3 Objects of type A that need to be processed and only on the final processing of an Object A can I move on to processing Objects of type B. Additionally, the processing of Objects of Type A are occurring in parallel from multiple deployed instances

Example:

Desired Behavior:

1. **ObjectA-1** - Update status -> IsLastObjectA -> false
2. **ObjectA-2** - Update status -> IsLastObjectA -> false
3. **ObjectA-3** - Update status -> IsLastObjectA -> true -> Begin processing Objects of type B

Current Behavior failing

1. **ObjectA-1** - Update status -> IsLastObjectA -> false
2. **ObjectA-2** - Update status (happens in parallel with ObjectA-3) -> IsLastObjectA (at this point all Object As are in complete status) -> true -> Begin processing Objects of type B (This should only occur once)
3. **ObjectA-3** - Update status (happens in parallel with ObjectA-2) -> IsLastObjectA (at this point all Object As are in complete status)-> true -> Begin processing Objects of type B (This should only occur once)

Ideally I want the transactions to happen in a serialized way (similar to that of isolation level Serializable). But not only does this hurt performance but also I don't have permission to increase ini trans params to the recommended 3. Also, a select for update and things of this locking nature cant be used because we only update the status once and there are no similar objects that are processed. They are all processed based on a unique primary key. Therefore, there is never One object A trying to update another. There is only reading the status from all other Object As after its current respective status has been updated.

I have tried different propagation types that oracle allows as well a locking technique and nothing has worked. Serializable seems to be the best option but I dont have the permissions to implement that

In the code snippet below this is a mocked version of the actual code. The endpoint in the controller gets called from a microservice that is listening to a messaging system queue. The service consumes off the message queue (This service is not shown)

```
 @Data
 public class ObjectA   {
    private int status;
    private Long id;
 }



@Service
// Lets assume, there is a listener before this call that picks up a message off a queue
// maps the json to that of objectA
// then calls this method    
public boolean processObjectA(final ObjectA objecta)  { 
    final boolean isLastUpdate;
    isLastUpdate = service.updateObjectAndIsLastObjectToProcess(objectA); // for simplicity, lets assume this calls the method in the controller
    
    if(isLastUpdate){
        //Call DB and gather all info realted to ObjectBs and begin to process
    }

}



public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectService objectService;

    @PutMapping("/updatestatus/islastobject")
    public boolean isLastObjectToUpdate(
        @RequestParam(name = "id") final Long id,
        @RequestParam(name = "status") final int statusCode) {

        final boolean updateStatus;
        final boolean hasLastObjectBeenProcessed;

        try {
            // Update object to complete status
            updateStatus = objectService.updateObject(id, statusCode);
            if (updateStatus) {
                //Verify if all ObjectA are in complete status
                hasLastObjectBeenProcessed = objectService.hasLastObjectBeenProcessed(id);
                return hasLastObjectBeenProcessed;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}                             

ORACLE queries used
//Update ObjectA to compelte status
updateStatus query = update Object_A o set o.status = 9 where o.id = id

// Verifies is all ObjectA are in complete (9) status
hasLastObjectBeenProcessed query = SELECT object.id FROM Object_A o ml WHERE o.status = 9
```

Comment: I could help if I could understand your data model and processing steps more clearly. Can you provide something closer to real pseudo-code?

Comment: I was hoping for some SQL?

Comment: "hasLastObjectBeenProcessed query = SELECT object.id FROM Object_A o ml WHERE o.status = 9" isn't pulling only one id, but the whole table. How is that telling you about just the last object? As for your concurrency problem, you only show one DML statement, the single row update. If that's all your code is doing to your data, you should be committing immediately after the update. Then you shouldn't be having concurrency issues.

Comment: So say that we have 3 ObjectAs. A1 (has already been processed and is in status 9), A2(in status 20), A3 (in status 20). A2 and A3 are processed in concurrent transactions.A2 and A3 have their statuses updated and commit almost simultaneously. They then call hasLastObject which will check the status of A1, A2 and A3 (All 3 objects in the table). Since all are in 9, this will return 3 (size of the table). Therefore this is the last object to be processed. But if we commit immediately after the update. Then A2 and A3 will think it is the last Object because the hasLast returns 3 for both @PaulW

Comment: It sounds like you want to know that the last one is the last one. But because they are concurrent sessions, on a multi-CPU machine two sessions might be simultaneously the "last one". That's an unsolvable problem, by definition. There is no "last". You can serialize this, or change your strategy so you are okay with both seeing they are last, or give up the notion of being last altogether, or resolve conflicting lasts with some other column value, like max(id) = my id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two possible statuses on each row ("Active" - this row needs to be processed, and "Completed", this row is done), how about a model like below for your "worker" threads  (pseudo-code)

```
work_to_be_done = 
  select count(*)
  from  table
  where status = 'Active'
  and   objtype = 'A'
  and   rownum = 1;

if work_to_be_done = 0 
  <move onto objtype = B>
else
  open cursor for
    select *
    from   table
    where  status = 'Active'
    and    objtype = 'A'
    for update skip locked;
  
  for each row in cursor
    process row
    update status to 'Completed';
end;
```

First we see if there is any work to be done for "A".  If this returns zero, then everyone has completed and committed their work and we're good to move onto "B".

If it returns non-zero, then you have active work to do, but some of that might already be being worked on by other threads. So we do a skip locked to find rows that *we* can work on.  It might be zero, but that's OK, we just loop around (maybe sleep a little) and then start from the top.  Eventually either *we* will find work to do, or we will find that all the work has been done and we can move on